# Update JSON object in outer object or insert a default one

Tags: json, rust

The below code is part of a [program](https://github.com/homeinfogmbh/digsigctl/) that, among other things, configures a Chromium profile:

```rust
#[cfg(target_family = "unix")]
use home::home_dir;
use rocket::serde::json::serde_json::Map;
use rocket::serde::json::{serde_json, Value};
use serde::Deserialize;
#[cfg(target_family = "windows")]
use std::env::var;
use std::fmt::{Debug, Display, Formatter};
use std::fs::{read_to_string, OpenOptions};
use std::io::Write;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use subprocess::{Popen, PopenConfig, Redirection};

#[cfg(target_family = "unix")]
const CHROMIUM_DEFAULT_PREFERENCES: &str = ".config/chromium/Default/Preferences";

#[cfg(target_family = "windows")]
const CHROMIUM_DEFAULT_PREFERENCES: &str = r"Google\Chrome\User Data\Default";

#[cfg(target_family = "unix")]
pub fn chromium_default_preferences() -> Option<PathBuf> {
    home_dir().map(|home| home.join(CHROMIUM_DEFAULT_PREFERENCES))
}

#[cfg(target_family = "windows")]
pub fn chromium_default_preferences() -> Option<PathBuf> {
    var("%LOCALAPPDATA%")
        .map(PathBuf::from)
        .map(|home| home.join(CHROMIUM_DEFAULT_PREFERENCES))
        .ok()
}

#[allow(clippy::enum_variant_names)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    SerdeError(serde_json::Error),
    IoError(std::io::Error),
    ChromiumDefaultPreferencesNotFound,
    NotAJsonObject(&'static str),
}

impl Display for Error {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::SerdeError(error) => <serde_json::Error as Display>::fmt(error, f),
            Self::IoError(error) => <std::io::Error as Display>::fmt(error, f),
            Self::ChromiumDefaultPreferencesNotFound => {
                write!(f, "Chrome / Chromium default preferences not found")
            }
            Self::NotAJsonObject(key) => write!(f, "not a JSON object: {key}"),
        }
    }
}

impl std::error::Error for Error {
    fn source(&self) -> Option<&(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)> {
        match self {
            Self::SerdeError(error) => Some(error),
            Self::IoError(error) => Some(error),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

impl From<std::io::Error> for Error {
    fn from(error: std::io::Error) -> Self {
        Self::IoError(error)
    }
}

impl From<serde_json::Error> for Error {
    fn from(error: serde_json::Error) -> Self {
        Self::SerdeError(error)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Config {
    url: String,
}

impl Config {
    #[must_use]
    pub fn url(&self) -> &str {
        self.url.as_str()
    }

    /// Applies the configuration to the system
    /// # Errors
    /// Returns an [`digsigctl::config::Error`] if the configuration could not be applied
    pub fn apply(&self) -> Result<(), anyhow::Error> {
        self.update()?;
        reload()?;
        Ok(())
    }

    fn update(&self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        let filename =
            chromium_default_preferences().ok_or(Error::ChromiumDefaultPreferencesNotFound)?;
        let mut value = load(&filename)?;
        let preferences = value
            .as_object_mut()
            .ok_or(Error::NotAJsonObject("preferences"))?;

        if let Some(session) = preferences.get_mut("session") {
            let session = session
                .as_object_mut()
                .ok_or(Error::NotAJsonObject("session"))?;
            session.insert("startup_urls".to_string(), vec![self.url.clone()].into());
            session.insert("restore_on_startup".to_string(), 4.into());
        } else {
            let mut session = Map::new();
            session.insert("startup_urls".to_string(), vec![self.url.clone()].into());
            session.insert("restore_on_startup".to_string(), 4.into());
            preferences.insert("session".to_string(), Value::Object(session));
        }

        save(&filename, &value)
    }
}

fn reload() -> subprocess::Result<Popen> {
    Popen::create(
        &["systemctl", "restart", "chromium.service"],
        PopenConfig {
            stdout: Redirection::None,
            detached: false,
            ..Default::default()
        },
    )
}

fn load(filename: impl AsRef<Path>) -> Result<Value, Error> {
    Ok(serde_json::from_str::<Value>(&read_to_string(filename)?)?)
}

fn save(filename: impl AsRef<Path>, value: &Value) -> Result<(), Error> {
    Ok(OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .truncate(true)
        .open(filename)?
        .write_all(serde_json::to_string(value)?.as_bytes())?)
}
```

My biggest issue with the above code is the `Config::update()` method.
I have duplicate lines that set the session keys I want to override.
I don't know how to resolve this, since the `else` case handles the case in which the object does not exist in the outer container and thus needs to be created and inserted.
Therefor I need to move the newly created object into the container when all is done, at which point I can no longer have references to it.
So I cannot write something like

```rust
...

        let mut map = Map::new();

        let mut session = if let Some(session) = preferences.get_mut("session") {
            session
                .as_object_mut()
                .ok_or(Error::NotAJsonObject("session"))?
        } else {
            preferences.insert("session".to_string(), Value::Object(map));
            &mut map
        };

        session.insert("startup_urls".to_string(), vec![self.url.clone()].into());
        session.insert("restore_on_startup".to_string(), 4.into());
...
```

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `map`
   --> src/config.rs:112:13
    |
104 |         let mut map = Map::new();
    |             ------- move occurs because `map` has type `rocket::serde::json::serde_json::Map<std::string::String, rocket::serde::json::Value>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
111 |             preferences.insert("session".to_string(), Value::Object(map));
    |                                                                     --- value moved here
112 |             &mut map
    |             ^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

Is there another way to de-duplicate those insert statements?

**Update**

I found a possible solution to de-duplicate the insert statements:

```rust
    fn update(&self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        let filename =
            chromium_default_preferences().ok_or(Error::ChromiumDefaultPreferencesNotFound)?;
        let mut value = load(&filename)?;
        let preferences = value
            .as_object_mut()
            .ok_or(Error::NotAJsonObject("preferences"))?;

        let default_session = Map::from_iter([
            (
                "startup_urls".to_string(),
                Value::Array(vec![Value::String(self.url.clone())]),
            ),
            ("restore_on_startup".to_string(), Value::Number(4.into())),
        ]);

        if let Some(session) = preferences.get_mut("session") {
            session
                .as_object_mut()
                .ok_or(Error::NotAJsonObject("session"))?
                .extend(default_session);
        } else {
            preferences.insert("session".to_string(), Value::Object(default_session));
        }

        save(&filename, &value)
    }
```

If you have other improvements to suggest, they'll be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more refactoring I handled the Chromium config updating as follows:

```rust
use super::error::Error;
use rocket::serde::json::serde_json::Map;
use rocket::serde::json::{serde_json, Value};
use std::convert::Into;
use std::fs::{read_to_string, OpenOptions};
use std::io::Write;
use std::path::Path;
use std::string::ToString;

/// Manage "Preferences" file of Chrome / Chromium webbrowsers
pub struct ChromiumPreferences(Value);

impl ChromiumPreferences {
    /// Load preferences from the given file
    ///
    /// # Errors
    /// Returns an `[digsigctl::config::error::Error]` if the file could not be read or deserialized
    pub fn load(filename: impl AsRef<Path>) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        Ok(Self(serde_json::from_str::<Value>(&read_to_string(
            filename,
        )?)?))
    }

    /// Saves preferences to the given file
    ///
    /// # Errors
    /// Returns an `[digsigctl::config::error::Error]` if the file could not be written or serialized
    pub fn save(&self, filename: impl AsRef<Path>) -> Result<(), Error> {
        Ok(OpenOptions::new()
            .write(true)
            .create(true)
            .truncate(true)
            .open(filename)?
            .write_all(serde_json::to_string(&self.0)?.as_bytes())?)
    }

    /// Updates the _session_ object or initializes it, if it is not present
    ///
    /// # Errors
    /// Returns an `[digsigctl::config::error::Error]` if the preferences file is corrupted
    pub fn update_or_init_session(&mut self, url: &str) -> Result<(), Error> {
        self.update_or_insert(
            "session",
            &[
                (
                    "startup_urls".to_string(),
                    Value::Array(vec![Value::String(url.to_string())]),
                ),
                ("restore_on_startup".to_string(), Value::Number(4.into())),
            ],
        )
    }

    /// Updates the _profile_ object or initializes it, if it is not present
    ///
    /// # Errors
    /// Returns an `[digsigctl::config::error::Error]` if the preferences file is corrupted
    pub fn update_or_init_profile(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        self.update_or_insert("profile", &[("exit_type".to_string(), "Normal".into())])
    }

    /// Updates the _sessions_ object or initializes it, if it is not present
    ///
    /// # Errors
    /// Returns an `[digsigctl::config::error::Error]` if the preferences file is corrupted
    pub fn update_or_init_sessions(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        self.update_or_insert("sessions", &[("session_data_status".to_string(), 3.into())])
    }

    fn update_or_insert(&mut self, key: &str, values: &[(String, Value)]) -> Result<(), Error> {
        update_or_insert(
            self.preferences()?,
            key,
            values
                .iter()
                .map(|(key, value)| (key.clone(), value.clone()))
                .collect::<Map<_, _>>(),
        );
        Ok(())
    }

    fn preferences(&mut self) -> Result<&mut Map<String, Value>, Error> {
        self.0
            .as_object_mut()
            .ok_or(Error::NotAJsonObject("preferences"))
    }
}

fn update_or_insert(parent: &mut Map<String, Value>, key: &str, value: Map<String, Value>) {
    if let Some(object) = parent.get_mut(key).and_then(Value::as_object_mut) {
        object.extend(value);
    } else {
        parent.insert(key.to_string(), Value::Object(value));
    }
}
```

This splits the Chromium configuration file handling from the passed `Config` object POST'ed to the webserver.
Since I now also update other objects within the outer JSON object, this also allows for code deduplication, since I now have a generic `update_or_insert()` method and corresponding function that can both be reused.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to de-duplicate the insert statements, by pattern matching on the return value of [`remove`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/struct.Map.html#method.remove), allowing us to start with a `serde_json::Map` which we can then update before slotting it back into `preferences`:

```rust
fn update(&self) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let filename =
        chromium_default_preferences().ok_or(Error::ChromiumDefaultPreferencesNotFound)?;
    let mut value = load(&filename)?;
    let preferences = value
        .as_object_mut()
        .ok_or(Error::NotAJsonObject("preferences"))?;

    let key = "session";
    let mut session = match preferences.remove(key) {
        Some(Value::Object(session)) => session,
        None => Map::new(),
        _ => return Err(Error::NotAJsonObject(key)),
    };
    session.insert("startup_urls".to_string(), vec![self.url.clone()].into());
    session.insert("restore_on_startup".to_string(), 4.into());
    preferences.insert(key.to_string(), Value::Object(session));

    save(&filename, &value)
}
```